# extracting "yearmon" from character format and calculating age in R

Tags: r, date

I have two columns of data:

```
DoB: yyyy/mm
Reported date: yyyy/mm/dd
```

Both are in character format.

I'd like to calculate an age, by subtracting DoB from Reported Date, without adding a fictional day to the DoB, so that the age comes out as 28.5 (meaning 28 and a half years old).

Please can someone help me with the coding, I'm struggling!

Many thanks from an R newbie.

Comment: Look into `lubridate` packages.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)

a <- "2010/02"
b <- "2014/12/25"
c <- ymd(b) - ymd(paste0(a, "/01"))  # I don't think this can be done without adding a fictional day
c <- as(c/365.25, "numeric")
```

What would you want the age to be if the dates are:

`DoB: 2015/01`

`Reported date: 2015/01/30`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, `lubridate` is a great package for working with dates.  You probably want some version using `difftime`.  You also can still use `ymd` for the yyyy/mm by setting `truncated=1` meaning the field can be missing.

```
df <- data.frame(DoB = c("1987/08", "1994/04"),
                 Report_Date = c("2015/03/05","2014/07/04"))

library(lubridate)

df$age_years <- with(df, 
                 as.numeric(
                   difftime(ymd(Report_Date), 
                            ymd(DoB, truncated=1)
                   )/365.25))
df
      DoB Report_Date   age_years
1 1987/08  2015/03/05 27.59206023
2 1994/04  2014/07/04 20.25735797
```

Unfortunately `difftime` doesn't have a 'years' unit so you also will need to divide the 'days' output that you get back.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `"yearmon"` class in zoo. It represents time as years + fraction (where fraction is in the set 0, 1/12, ..., 11/12) and so does *not* require that fictitious days be added:

```
library(zoo)
as.yearmon("2012/01/10", "%Y/%m/%d") - as.yearmon("1983/07", "%Y/%m")
```

giving:

```
[1] 28.5
```